# Probability ( kth order statistics <x , (k+1)th order stat >x)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, order-statistics

consider $n$ iid draws according to some cdf $F$.

What is the probability of the following event:
the $k^{\text{th}}$ highest value is smaller than $x$ AND the $k+1$ highest value is larger than $x$.

Thanks for helping out a confused mind.

Comment: Did you transform the hint below into a full solution?

Comment: Yes, I did. I was indeed confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** You want the probability that $k$ of the draws are smaller than $x$, and $n-k$ of the draws are larger than $x$, occurring in no particular order.